# Trigger the launch of another PHP file, but return right now

Tags: php

Is it possible to launch a task (some long processing) but return right now the page for the user in PHP?

#### index.php

```
<?php

...

// the page rendering is finished here, so don't make the user wait, return now
launch('do_some_10_seconds_long_processing.php')
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, `shell_exec('php other.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &');`

But you should use a proper worker queue instead, such as [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).

Comment: As discussed, this will be launched with http daemon's user.